# NLog ProgramData path

Tags: logging, path, nlog

When a NLog.config has an absolute path, all is working nice:

```
 <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  autoReload="true"
  internalLogLevel="Info"
  internalLogFile="F:\ProgramData\MyApp\myfolder\nlog.txt">
```

if I try to use a specialfolder variable, it fails to work:

```
internalLogFile="${specialfolder:folder=CommonApplicationData}\MyApp\myfolder\nlog.txt">
```

What *NLog.config* path should I use to make NLog use the **ProgramData** folder **without using an absolute path**?

I use NLog v. 2.0 on Windows 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use layout renderers ${...} in the internalLogFile property. They are for target's layout only:

```
<target layout="${...}" />
```

Try to use relative path like "..\myfolder\nlog.txt"

Comment: Yes, for targets it works. For internalLogFile I didn't manage to make it work with relative path either. Nevertherless, +1 for making it clear that renderers `${...}` are for targets only. Thanks!

Comment: it is not answering the question though :(

Answer (score 2):

Based on [NLog Special folders](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Special-Folder-Layout-Renderer):

fileName="${specialfolder:folder=ApplicationData}/Program/file.txt"

May do the trick